# Meta tag merge request: [scope] & [allowed-topics]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, meta

I draw your attention to the following tags on Meta: [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics).

[scope](/questions/tagged/scope) is on 52 questions, has a tag wiki and excerpt.

[allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics) is on 18 questions, with *no* tag wiki or excerpt.

Further, "scope" is more-or-less a standard tag on Meta sites. Examples: [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/scope/info), [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/scope/info).

They cover the same ground. As [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) is older, has more questions, has a wiki and excerpt, and is a *de facto* standard, it should be the master and [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics) should be a synonym of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point, Al – done. Remark: Some questions even carried both tags …